# order_by does not sort Swedish UTF-8 characters ÅÄÖ correctly on production server

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm experiencing some issues with my production droplet @ DigitalOcean when sorting querysets. The Swedish characters ÅÄÖ are treated as A and O, which is not expected or desired. This works locally.

I've dabbled with the locales on the server, and they seem to be alright.

- Django version: 1.11
- Python version: 3.5.2

If anyone have experienced & solved similar issues, it would be great to hear how you solved it!

**Model definition**

```
class County(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**How the queryset is sorted.**

```
County.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

Comment: What database are you using, and what character collation is set in the database?